# Dynamically Remove ToolStripMenuItems from MenuStrip with parent's C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

Hello to all the community of stackoverflow, I came to you today to ask a help with a problem I'm trying for several days to fix.

I need to find a recursive algorithm that is able to find the children, if not then have the parent (submodule) has to be removed/hidden.
The Parent Objects have a tag called: submodule.
Children objects have one called: moduleoption

I have the following scenarios:

```
Main
  L Item (Tag: moduleoption)
  L SubMenu 2 (Tag: submodule)
      L Item (Tag: moduleoption)
      L Item (Tag: moduleoption)
      L SubMenu 2.1 (Tag: submodule)  <-- Remove/Hide
  L SubMenu 3 (Tag: submodule) <-- Remove/Hide
```

In this scenarios i want to hide: SubMenu 2.1, SubMenu 3, because they do not have children.

--

```
Main <-- All are empty submodules, Remove/Hide MenuStrip
  L SubMenu 1 (Tag: submodule) <-- Remove/Hide
  L SubMenu 2 (Tag: submodule) <-- Remove/Hide
  L SubMenu 3 (Tag: submodule) <-- Remove/Hide
```

In this second case as all submodules are empty then it is not necessary to show menustrip Control.

My Code:

```
private ToolStripMenuItem MenuStripHide(MenuStrip MenuS)
{

            if (MenuS.HasDropDownItems)
            {
                foreach (ToolStripMenuItem ToolStrip in MenuS.DropDownItems)
                {
                    if (ToolStrip.HasDropDownItems == false)
                    {
                        ToolStrip.Visible = false;
                    }

                    //call recursively
                    GetSubMenuStripItems((ToolStripMenuItem)ToolStrip);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MenuS.Visible = false;
            }

    return menuItem;
}
```

It took days thinking around this, since advance thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, I think the following will work for you. It starts with `RemoveMenuItems`, the root menu strip. It will cycle through all of it's children to `RemoveToolStripItems`. I left it at a base class in case you have non-`ToolStripMenuItem` objects in the menu it can still work. `RemoveToolStripItems` checks that the call to it is not forcing it to hide (in the event a parent needs to hide) and that the Tag is not of type {submodule}. If either of these conditions are met, itself and all children are set to `Available = false` (the `ToolStripItem` equivalent of `Visible = False`). If all children are hidden, then the control also sets Available to false.

```
    private void RemoveMenuItems(MenuStrip menuStrip1) {
        foreach (object menuItem in menuStrip1.Items) {
            RemoveToolStripItems(menuItem as ToolStripItem, false);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks to see if the ToolStripItem that is passed to it has a tag type of {submodule},
    /// if it does then hide all of the children (if applicable). If all children are hidden, hide current.
    /// </summary>
    private bool RemoveToolStripItems(ToolStripItem toolStripItem, bool forceHide) {
        if (toolStripItem == null) { return false; }
        ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = toolStripItem as ToolStripMenuItem;
        bool hideCurrent = forceHide || ((toolStripItem.Tag as submodule) != null);
        if (menuItem != null && menuItem.HasDropDownItems) {
            bool allChildrenAreHidden = true;
            foreach (object dropDownItem in menuItem.DropDownItems) {
                allChildrenAreHidden &= RemoveToolStripItems(dropDownItem as ToolStripItem, hideCurrent);
            }
            hideCurrent |= allChildrenAreHidden;
        }
        toolStripItem.Available = !hideCurrent ;
        return hideCurrent;
    }
```